# Why do "streamers" always use plural form to refer to "we" when they mean "I"?

Tags: royal-we

I've been watching a lot of live video streams on Twitch in the last couple of years.

One thing I've noticed and which bothers me is that they frequently say things like:

> We've almost beat this level now!
>
> Last week, we almost finished the painting.
>
> We only need a few more subs to get new emotes!

Etc...

Always "we" -- not "I". After all, it's the person streaming who is doing all of the gaming/art/ASMR/work. I assume that they must all read some kind of list provided by Twitch which tells them "tricks" to make people more willing to pay them money, and stay around, but it really bothers me when they use "we" and pretend as if they are a "multi-person operation" or that the chatters/viewers are somehow part of it, other than money-providing entities.

It seems so silly somehow. Us viewers/chatters are supposed to feel like we are part of the streamer's "thing" by being included in a "we" or "us", ultimately for the goal of providing them with more money? To me, it just feels embarrassing and weird, yet it's so extremely common that it's become expected or even an "unwritten rule".

Even the smallest streamers seem to have the mentality that they are supposed to and will grow in viewers and thus "subs" (subscribers, meaning people who pay them money), using every trick they can think of to make that happen. It just seems disingenuous to me.

Comment: I think you're correct in your speculation that it's about making viewers feel included for the purposes of monetary gain, but this feels more like a rant about streamers than it does a question about the English language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the motivations of a group of people.

Comment: It's the "royal we".

Comment: What makes you suspect that this is a money-making trick that has grown in popularity over time? I think it's a rhetorical device for making the listener feel included, which has been very popular for decades, if not centuries, if not millennia. I've streamed once or twice and the idea of using "I" instead of "we" never even crossed my mind.

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by the conscious adoption of what is known as "the inclusive we". The "we" implies that you and the writer are friends and share similar views and experiences.

Psychologically, it is used to minimise conflict and encourage agreement.

The trouble with such tricks of style is (i) they can become intrusive (ii) once you realise what is happening, or you do not agree, a certain antithesis sets in.